# Accessing BuildContext while splitting files in flutter

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to setup a `InheritedWidget` in flutter allowing a model to be accessed from anywhere in the application.

It works great until I try to split my application into multiple files. It seems that calling `context.inheritFromWidgetOfExactType(...)` only workes if the called from the same file as where the `InheritedWidget` is inserted into the tree. Simply by moving a block of code from one file to another results in `null` being returned from that method.

The code is as follows:

The basic app is setup from the demo app
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'views/home.dart';

```
void main() async {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new StateContainer(
      model: new AppState(),
      child: new MaterialApp(
        title: 'Flutter Demo',
        theme: new ThemeData(
          primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        ),
        home: new HomePage(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The `InheritedWidget` is defined with a model as follows:

```
class StateContainer extends InheritedWidget {
  final AppState model;

  StateContainer({Key key, this.model, Widget child})
      : super(key: key, child: child);

  @override
  bool updateShouldNotify(StateContainer old) {
    return false;
  }

  static AppState of(BuildContext context) {
    return (context.inheritFromWidgetOfExactType(StateContainer)
            as StateContainer).model;
  }
}

class AppState {
  final String test = "Hi";
}
```

Finally, the HomePage is defined by:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:ftest/main.dart';

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var model = StateContainer.of(context);
    return Container(
      child: Center(
        child: Text(model.test),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

With this last block in the same file as the other two, the app works as expected. By simply moving it into a new file however, the error message `The getter 'model' was called on null.` is thrown.

I can only guess that somewhere the BuildContext isn't being passed properly, but nothing I've tried as fixed it. Any ideas?

Comment: Is StateContainer defined in the main.dart?

Comment: Yes, everything except the `HomePage` class is in main.dart

Comment: Due to that post, if you extract your `StateContainer` to a new file, this should solve the problem

Comment: Thankyou so much, that fixed it